# reading data from excel into SAS and converting character to numeric

Tags: excel, oracle, sas

I am reading data from an excel file in SAS and inserting the values to an oracle table. The oracle table has a numeric column. If the excel file has numbers, it works fine. But if the column is left blank in the excel file, it is read as a character value and insertion to oracle fails.

Is it possible to convert the column to numeric if its is blank, but read it as is if its has a number?

Thanks!

Comment: What type of excel file do you have?  The older XLS format?  The current XLSX format? How are you getting the excel file into a SAS dataset?  Note: If you actually just have a text file, like a CSV file, that you think of as an excel file then it is much easier to control how it is read since you can just write a data step to read the text file directly and you will have complete control over the format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below case statement worked for me.

```
case 
when missing(input(cats(COLUMN_VALUE), best8.)) THEN input(cats(COLUMN_VALUE), best8.) 
when not missing(input(cats(COLUMN_VALUE), best8.)) THEN input(cats(COLUMN_VALUE), best8.) 
end as COLUMN_VALUE
```

Comment: Since the same value is always selected you don't need the CASE.  There is no informat named best and why limit yourself to 8 character strings?  Use `input(cats(column_value),32.) as COLUMN_VALUE`

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that SAS is reading this column as a character and you cannot convert it directly within the file. This happens sometimes: maybe you don't have authorization to do it, or maybe it's just not working like you're expecting. SAS can go from character to numeric and numeric to character with two functions: `input()` and `put()`.

**Going from Character to Numeric: `input()`**

**in**put() is for changing character data **in**to numbers.

This is great for reading in dates, currency, comma-separated numbers, etc. If you need your data as a number, use this function. Its syntax is:

`num_var = input(char_var, informat.);`

In your case, let's say we always expect numbers to be here even if it's missing. We'll use the `8.` informat for our variable of interest, `my_var`.

```
data want;
    set have_excel(rename=(my_var = my_var_char) );
    
    my_var = input(my_var_char, 8.);
    
    drop my_var_char;
run;
```

Note that we need to create a new variable. We rename the variable of interest to something else, then create a new version of the variable of interest that is a number. In SAS, just like many other languages and database systems, when a variable is declared as a character or number, it is *always* a character or a number.

**Going from Numeric to Character: `put()`**

**put()** is for **put**ting a number to a character or a character to another character.

This is great for converting SAS dates to characters, adding custom formats, converting a character to another character, etc. The syntax is:

`char_var = put(num_var, format.);`

OR:

`char_var = put(char_var, format.);`

Note the previous use case: with `put()`, you can convert characters to other characters. This is very handy for standardizing values or even merging data using a format.

For example: let's convert a number to a comma-separated character number.

```
data want;
    char_number = put(1234, comma.);
run;
```

Output:

```
char_number
1,234
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Stu Sztukowski! But when I rename the column, and create a new version with number datatype, the column is converted to number if it is read as character from the excel. But, if the column is read a number from excel, the values in the column goes missing.